# How do you find a quoted string with specific word in a log message using grok pattern

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I have a log message from my server with the format below:

```
{"host":"a.b.com","source_type":"ABCD"}
```

I have this grok pattern so far but it accepts any word in double quotation.

```
\A%{QUOTEDSTRING}:%{PROG}
```

how can I change "QUOTEDSTRING" that only check for "host"?
"host" is not at the beginning of the message all the time and it can be found in the middle of message as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think regex would match your needs, but what about show some possibilities of the log you talking about? Grok also capable of using regex.

Comment: I need to find host and it's value and add it as a new field in elastic. the current grok pattern just look for quoted strings and can't check the the word itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question specified that "**host**" can be anywhere between in the log, you can use the following:

```
\{(\"%{GREEDYDATA:data_before}\",)?(\"host\":\"%{DATA:host_value}\")?(,\"%{GREEDYDATA:data_after}\")?\}
```

Explanation :

1. **data_before** stores the optional data before host type entry is found. You can separate it more as per your need
2. **host** : this stores the host value
3. **data_after** stores the optional data after host type entry is found. You can seaprate it more as per your need

Example :

1. `{"host":"a.b.com","source_type":"ABCD"}`

Output :

```
{
  "data_before": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "host_value": [
    [
      "a.b.com"
    ]
  ],
  "data_after": [
    [
      "source_type":"ABCD"
    ]
  ]
}
```

2. `{"host":"a.b.com"}`

Output :

```
{
  "data_before": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "host_value": [
    [
      "a.b.com"
    ]
  ],
  "data_after": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

3. `{"source_type":"ABCD","host":"a.b.com","data_type":"ABCD"}`

Output :

```
{
  "data_before": [
    [
      "source_type":"ABCD"
    ]
  ],
  "host_value": [
    [
      "a.b.com"
    ]
  ],
  "data_after": [
    [
      "data_type":"ABCD"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Tip : Use the following resources to tune and test your logging patterns :

- [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)
- [Grok Patterns Full List](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/grok-patterns)

Comment: thanks for your solution! it worked well for me!:)))